# How to make use of NumericQ[x] = True (and use it safely)?

Tags: programming, evaluation, assignment, assumptions

---

### Basic Issue:

I'm trying to understand the proper use of `NumericQ`'s "magical" capabilities. Please consider the examples below. Actual question and some links are at the very end.

---

### Example 1:

Many of you are aware that `NumericQ` can be used as follows, without unprotecting:

```
In[1]:= 
        Remove[x, y];
        NumericQ[x] = True;
        (*and apparently using TagSet instead of Set makes no difference because \
        you can't direct, let alone see, where this type of info is stored \ 
        anyways.*)
```

The following output is as expected:

```
In[3]:= 
        NumericQ[x]
        NumericQ[y]

Out[3]= True
Out[4]= False
```

Go ahead and make the following assignment:

```
In[5]:= x = y

Out[5]= y
```

The following behavior is interesting, but quite reasonable. It seems logical that setting `x` to `y` would somehow globally overwrite the "magical" numeric property:

```
In[6]:= 
        NumericQ[x]
        NumericQ[y]

Out[6]= False
Out[7]= False
```

#### *Hmmm... #1*

...Well, at least I thought it would have 'overwritten' the behavior!!

```
In[8]:= 
        (*Note: Could also use Clear[x] or ClearAll[x] *)
        x =.
        NumericQ[x]

Out[9]= True
```

---

### Example 2:

Now suppose we had made the assignment `x = y` *first* (before evaluating `NumericQ[x] = True`):

```
In[12]:= 
         Remove[x, y];
         x = y

Out[13]= y
```

#### *Hmmm... #2*

Now *Mathematica* has pushed the numerical property onto `y` as well.

```
In[14]:= 
         NumericQ[x] = True
         NumericQ[y]

Out[14]= True
Out[15]= True
```

---

---

### Question:

How can one put `NumericQ[x] = True` to good/powerful use---and just as importanltly, in light of the above examples, how can it be used safely? (i.e., Can this behavior be localized somehow? Used safely within a package?---intuition makes me wonder if the only way to isolate the behavior would be to store impacted symbols in a junk context or something.)

**Links of Interest:**

@Szabolcs 'Mathematica Tricks' page; scroll down about half way or search for `NumericQ`: http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php

MathGroup Discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/buxdxzwV4bY

Comment: Daniel's reply in the MathGroup thread gives a lot of relevant details on why this was implemented and how it was intended to be used. That would probably be the answer you're looking for

Comment: You may also want to look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408310/unwanted-evaluation-in-assignments-in-mathematica-why-it-happens-and-how-to-de)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The behaviour you observed is completely independent of `NumericQ`. It could also be seen with a function `foo` which has the initial definition `foo[_]=False`.

## Example 1:

Initially you define `NumerixQ[x]=True`, which tells Mathematica that whenever it evaluates the expression `NumericQ[x]`, it should evaluate to `True`. Since for symbols, it is pre-defined to return `False`, it will do so for `y` (`Out[3]`, `Out[4]`).

Then you define `x=y` and evaluate `NumericQ[x]`. Since `NumericQ` doesn't have any special attributes, the normal evaluation order applies, which means to first evaluate the argument (evaluating `x` gives `y`), and then to evaluate the resulting expression `NumericQ[y]` which of course gives `False`. Note that `NumericQ` is *not* applied to `x` (which would still give true).

Next, you *remove* the definition of `x` (but still don't touch the definition of `NumericQ` where the value of `NumericQ[x]` is still stored). Therefore the symbol `x` is self-evaluating again, and you again evaluate `NumericQ[x]`, resulting in `True`.

## Example 2:

Here you start with `x=y`, which makes `x` evauate to `y`. When you then use `NumericQ[x]=True` you trigger what I consider the most confusing behaviour of Mathematica (which still isn't directly related to `NumericQ`): While `Set` (`=`) has the attribute `HoldFirst`, that does *not* mean that the left hand side isn't evaluated at all; the argument `x` is *still* evaluated to `y` before the assignment is evaluated, so the assignment that is ultimately evaluated is `NumericQ[y]=True`. Your subsequent evaluation `NumericQ[y]` therefore gives `True`. You can see this confusing behaviour also in the following example:

```
x = y
f[x] = 3
x =.
{f[x], f[y]}
(*
==> {f[x], 3}
*)
```

Comment: What you wrote seems helpful, but please give me some time to digest. I'm still unclear as to when using NumericQ in this manner can be of use though. Putting my inquiry another way, the behavior is certainly confusing (to me at least) and I consider that a 'cost' of use, so what are the potential 'benefits'? And is it possible to minimize potential confusion by localizing somehow?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The explanation of 'example 2' helps greatly. As for 'example 1', I guess part of my worry/confusion/wonder is that, although I use Unset in the example, ClearAll[x] doesn't kill NumberQ[x]:=True either--- only Remove[x] does. (Not apparent to me why that would be the case, I guess.)

Comment: @telefunkenvf14: The reason would be that with `NumberQ[x]:=True` you add a new rule to `NumberQ`, not to `x`. However even with `NumericQ[x]^:=True` (which should normally associate the definition with `x` instead of `NumericQ`), `ClearAll[x]` *still* doesn't seem to work. Strange. Apparently there's a special handling for assignments to `NumericQ` which isn't properly accounted for by `ClearAll`. Of course you can always add an explicit `NumericQ[x]=False` after `ClearAll`.

Answer (score 7):

Let's see if this clarifies your issues with the usefulness of the construct. Probably not because I am not sure I understood them.

You want to have some numeric value, represented by a symbol. A constant, a unit, who knows. You do

```
NumericQ[symb]=True
```

Now, any function defined to only receive numeric input (`_?NumericQ`) will know it can take `symb` as an argument, and also numeric functions applied to `symb`. This becomes more useful coupled with a definition like

```
N[symb]=2958429384523542.3543;
```

These two definitions would allow you to keep your results exact and symbolic while at the same time being able to turn them into numeric values when needed and use Mathematica's numerical functions.